# How do I bulk generate/grant download permissions on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am in a situation. I have a downloadable product, with over 3500 customers buying it so far. While updating the downloadable product, apparently I messed up and some how removed access to the current 3500+ clients resulting in many confused emails. The customers are still shown as buying the digital product in their account purchases.

So that brings me to desperately ask, how do I bulk generate/grant download permissions on WooCommerce to the customers that have already bought my downloadable product?

I'm thinking about a SQL query, but not exactly sure what I would need to move and to where? What makes it even more difficult is I only need the permissions to be granted to customers of the specific product!

Comment: Not exactly sure about the table, columns or the code but [this](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_downloadable_product_permissions/) might be useful if you have or can gather an array of order id's.

Comment: @Ekin Thank you so much for the response. I do have the order ID's. However where about would I place the ID's in the code? Where would I also place the product ID?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution. You can place this code to `functions.php`, open any page in backend or frontend (to run functions.php) and then comment or delete this code. It will not affect orders which already have download permissions.

```
add_action('init','my_activate_download_permissions');
function my_activate_download_permissions() {

$orders = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'    => 'wc-completed',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );

foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order->ID, false );
}}
```

Comment: Does it work? I put on functions.php but still I dont see any effect!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Here's link to documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_downloadable_product_permissions.html

Important thing is that you should have all files existing and available for download.

Answer (score 0):

@Tyree B. Hope you have resolved the issue, if yes then please share here else you can follow below solution:

1. Loop through your all users and get their order (order no.) and add the new downloadable product in the existing order using wc_add_order_item woocommerce function (You will also need to add product meta like quantity, priduct id etc.)
2. Loop through all customers and create a new order (gift order using code) for each customer and add product to the order. As per woocommerce rule/functionality automatically all user can download product from their my-account under download link.

Hopes it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a plugin Booster for Woocommerce (https://booster.io/features/woocommerce-orders/) that have a "Regenerate bulk permission download" option, u can activate manually our periodically